# File attachment and handling validation errors with Rails and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment

I have a form to send a message with attachments.

- User select files to attach
- Press submit and wait (long time) until all the file are uploaded
- The user forgot to type the message so the validation failed
- The user need to upload all the files again (long time)

Is there a simple way to make rails to remember the already uploaded files? (I have been using paperclip)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create the `Message` object initially with default (passing) values when you start uploading the file and then just issue a PUT request to update the message object using the form.

This way, the `Message` object is valid upon creation and the only thing you're validating is that the update information is valid as well (if it's not, the message will just have the default value and the user won't have to re-upload the file).

You can set up the database attribute (via a Rails migration) to have a set default value so you don't have to do this in the controller.

```
change_column_default(:messages, :content, "You have a new message!")
```

Comment: This is a good idea. What I am doing at the moment is to force a save without validation also in case the record is invalid but I was wondering if there could be something simpler. For example something similar to the natural behavior of rails where, if the data is not valid, the form is already pre-filled with the data that user already input.

Comment: You would have to switch to CarrierWave to keep the uploaded file in the cache if you wanted that sort of behavior.  Paperclip is not able to keep the already uploaded file around during validation errors so the user would have to upload it all over again.  If you want to keep using Paperclip, I'd recommend the sort of setup I describe above.

Comment: Personally, I use CarrierWave and it's pretty easy to set up.  It's just extra work if you want to switch your current set up.  Also, the caching feature (for already uploaded files) doesn't work on Heroku since they have a read-only file system... just something else to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix this on a recent project using PaperClip. It's a bit hacky but it works. I've tried calling cache_images() using after_validation and before_save in the model but it fails on create for some reason that I can't determine so I just call it from the controller instead. Hopefully this saves someone else some time!

model:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessor :logo_cache

  has_attached_file :logo

  def cache_images
    if logo.staged?
      if invalid?
        FileUtils.cp(logo.queued_for_write[:original].path, logo.path(:original))
        @logo_cache = encrypt(logo.path(:original))
      end
    else
      if @logo_cache.present?
        File.open(decrypt(@logo_cache)) {|f| assign_attributes(logo: f)}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def decrypt(data)
    return '' unless data.present?
    cipher = build_cipher(:decrypt, 'mypassword')
    cipher.update(Base64.urlsafe_decode64(data).unpack('m')[0]) + cipher.final
  end

  def encrypt(data)
    return '' unless data.present?
    cipher = build_cipher(:encrypt, 'mypassword')
    Base64.urlsafe_encode64([cipher.update(data) + cipher.final].pack('m'))
  end

  def build_cipher(type, password)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('DES-EDE3-CBC').send(type)
    cipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(password)
    cipher
  end

end
```

controller:

```
def create
  @shop = Shop.new(shop_params)
  @shop.user = current_user
  @shop.cache_images

  if @shop.save
    redirect_to account_path, notice: 'Shop created!'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def update
  @shop = current_user.shop
  @shop.assign_attributes(shop_params)
  @shop.cache_images

  if @shop.save
    redirect_to account_path, notice: 'Shop updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

view:

```
= f.file_field :logo
= f.hidden_field :logo_cache

- if @shop.logo.file?
  %img{src: @shop.logo.url, alt: ''}
```

Comment: it says that paperclip doest have staged. 

if logo.staged? --> undefined method `staged?' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x007fb431cf53b8>